# Retrieve row from sqlite with only part of column's data

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

How would I retrieve a specific row in a `SQLite` database, when I only have a part of a column's data?

Following table, named `foo`:

```
| id | randomKey   |
|  1 | af202fn02fe |
|  2 | 02fe9fwefew |
```

Now I want to get the `id`, where the `randomKey` starts with `af202`, which would be `1`.

How would my `SQL-Query` look like?

```
'SELECT id FROM foo WHERE randomKey = ?', []
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `LIKE` clause. In a `LIKE` clause, the `%` operator is used to wild-card data:

```
SELECT id FROM foo WHERE randomKey LIKE 'af202%'
```

`%` will match any or no characters.

1. Starts with: `LIKE 'af202%'`
2. Ends with: `LIKE %af202'`
3. Contains: `LIKE '%af202%'`

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
SELECT id FROM foo WHERE randomKey LIKE 'af202%'
```

The `%` is SQLITE's wildcard, so you'll only get the records that has a `randomKey` starting with `af202`.